# Any way to block access to Tor's directory server for bridge testing purposes? (Simulating a restricted network)

Tags: tor

For testing purposes, I would like to simulate a restricted network that would block access to Tor's directory server.

In other words, I would like to reproduce this error that would normally occur if one is on a restricted network:

```
[warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server.
```

Anyone know how to achieve this, or what server ip I should be blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Tor doesn't have a single directory server.  Newer versions will try to contact [directory authorities](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/app/config/auth_dirs.inc) and [directory fallbacks](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/app/config/fallback_dirs.inc).  The fallback directory list updates occasionally.

See [Section 5.1](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n3596) of the Tor directory specification for more details.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to block this list in order to test Tor's use of bridges?

Comment: If it's solely for testing, the easiest way might be to download the Tor source, edit those configs to reduce down to 1 authority and 1 fallback, then block those two specific addresses with a firewall. Otherwise you'd have to add all those address/port combinations into a firewall.

Comment: Is there an easier way to achieve this rather than compiling Tor from scratch? Possibly through some of its configurations to limit the dir authorities and fallbacks?

Comment: Looks like there are config options for [FallbackDir](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#FallbackDir) and [UseDefaultFallbackDirs](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#UseDefaultFallbackDirs) which can help simulate that. Just set a FallbackDir line to an address that isn't a directory.